# Get value from resx in Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I created an `App_GlobalResources` folder and added relevant resx files for the appropriate country in an ASP Net site.

I then add a key and value to the file. All displays on the site as required.

I am now trying to retrieve the value from this resx file from a class library, mainly using the below code

```
ResourceManager lang = new ResourceManager("Resource.en-AU",  Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
string value = lang.GetString(Key);
return value;
```

but the code crashes (second line) with the error

***Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resource.en-AU.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources.ufgcy-ty" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.***

So i then tried

```
ResourceManager myManager = new ResourceManager(typeof("NOTHING AVAILABLE HERE"));  // Seems like its expecting a resource file but since its a class library i cant do this
string myString = myManager.GetString("StringKey");
```

This leads me to believe that i need another way to retrieve the value from a country resx file in a Class Library but not seeing any examples of how to do this OR i need to move the existing resource files from the website to the Class Library and then copy over to the site everytime i make a change but i dont know if this is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = 
    new ResourceManager("Resources.xxx", Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
string myString = resourceManager.GetString("StringKey");
```

where `xxx` is name of your resource file, without `.resx` extension and without culture name (in your case, name should be `Resource` (without `.en-au`).

ResourceManager will try to load specified resource file for current culture, depending on `CurrentUICulture`. If your server is set to English (Australian) language/regional settings/Culture, it will try to load `Resource.en-au` if your culture is set to, let's say, Romanian, it will try to find `Resource.ro`. If such file isn't found, it will fallback to default one, the one without culture name.

Alternatively, you can load resources like this:

```
[Resources namespace].[Resource file name].ResourceManager.GetString("StringKey")
```

`Resources namespace` is Namespace of your resource file (default `Resources`, but you can see real namespace in your resource file's `.Designer.cs` file) and `resource file name` is filename of `.resx` file, without extension or culture.

So, you can try like this:

```
string myString = Resources.Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("StringKey");
```